# By group: sum of variable values under condition

Tags: r

Sum of var values by group with certain values excluded conditioned on the other variable. 
How to do it elegantly without transposing?
So in the table below for each (fTicker, DATE_f), I seek to sum the values of *wght* with the value of *wght* conditioned on sTicker excluded from the sum.

In the table below, (excl_val,sTicker=A) |(fTicker=XLK, DATE_f = 6/20/2003) = wght_AAPL_6/20/2003_XLK + wght_AA_6/20/2003_XLK but not the wght for sTicker=A

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| sTicker | fTicker |  DATE_f   |    wght     |  excl_val   |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| A       | XLK     | 6/20/2003 | 0.087600002 | 1.980834016 |
| A       | XLK     | 6/23/2003 | 0.08585     | 1.898560068 |
| A       | XLK     | 6/24/2003 | 0.085500002 |             |
| AAPL    | XLK     | 6/20/2003 | 0.070080002 |             |
| AAPL    | XLK     | 6/23/2003 | 0.06868     |             |
| AAPL    | XLK     | 6/24/2003 | 0.068400002 |             |
| AA      | XLK     | 6/20/2003 | 1.910754014 |             |
| AA      | XLK     | 6/23/2003 | 1.829880067 |             |
| AA      | XLK     | 6/24/2003 | 1.819775    |             |
|         |         |           |             |             |
|         |         |           |             |             |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

There are several fTicker groups with many sTicker in them (10 to 70), some sTicker may belong to several fTicker. The end result should be an excl_val for each sTicker on each DATE_f and for each fTicker.

I did it by transposing in SAS with resulting file about 6 gb but the same approach in R, blew memory up to 40 gb and it's basically unworkable.

In R, I got as far as this

```
weights$excl_val  <- with(weights, aggregate(wght, list(fTicker, DATE_f), sum, na.rm=T))
```

but it's just a simple sum (without excluding the necessary observation) and there is mismatch between rows length. If i could condition the sum to exclude the sTicker obs for wght from the summation, i think it might work.

About the excl_val length: i computed it in excel, for just 2 cells, that's why it's short

Thank you!

Arsenio

Answer (score 1):

When you have data in a data.frame, it is better if the rows are meaningful
(in particular, the columns should have the same length):
in this case, `excl_val` looks like a separate vector. 
After putting the information it contains in the data.frame, 
things become easier.

```
# Sample data
k <- 5
d <- data.frame(
  sTicker = rep(LETTERS[1:k], k),
  fTicker = rep(LETTERS[1:k], each=k),
  DATE_f = sample( seq(Sys.Date(), length=2, by=1), k*k, replace=TRUE ),
  wght = runif(k*k)
)
excl_val <- sample(d$wght, k)
# Add a "valid" column to the data.frame
d$valid <- ! d$wght %in% excl_val
# Compute the sum
library(plyr)
ddply(d, c("fTicker","DATE_f"), summarize, sum=sum(wght[valid]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I ran it and the end result is a table of fTicker, DATE_f and sum. How can i get the sTicker column back in the table like in the question?

Comment: You can use `transform` instead of `summarize`: `ddply(d, c("fTicker","DATE_f"), transform, sum=sum(wght))`.

Comment: i see, i think this is a bit different because it gives the same value of excl for different sTicker on the same date and in the same fTicker.`
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   sTicker fTicker     DATE_f       wght valid       sum  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1        A       A 2012-02-21 0.14107461 FALSE 2.1644542 |
| 2        B       A 2012-02-21 0.54263663  TRUE 2.1644542 |
| 3        C       A 2012-02-21 0.60238962  TRUE 2.1644542 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+`

Comment: I am not sure my `valid` column contains what you want.
Instead of creating the `excl_val` vector separately
and trying to force it back into the data.frame,
it is probably easier to directly create that `valid` column.